# Obj-C iPhone architecture regarding instantiation of classes

Tags: objective-c, architecture

I have a noob question regarding how to architect my iPhone app.

I have two main components, a map and an audio player, both self contained classes (MapController and AudioController). I read this great article and am trying to apply it to my app:

http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/

I have a third class, WebServices, that handles uploading POST data to my server as well as making queries to external API's.

My question:

1. Do I import header files, and create a new instance of WebServices in both the map controller, and the audio player? And then each controller can reference it's own WebServices for queries?
2. Or, should I create one WebServices instance on the RootController, and then pass this to the map and audio controllers on init?

In particular, I'm interested in which approach consumes memory more efficiently. Or if it doesn't matter at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point Zero**

Do not resort to singletons, and *especially* not in multithreaded contexts. You can search this site if you need explanations (hint: the reasons against them are quite similar in OO languages similar to ObjC. e.g. C++, Java, C#...).

**To share, or not?**

It ultimately depends on the behavior your design *needs*, but I favor Option #1 as the default.

- If you need multiple instances, do not be afraid create multiple (unless you have a really, really, really good reason not to).
- If they are heavy to construct, consider what immutable data they can share.
- Favor smaller, specialized objects (`WebServices` may be huge). Smaller objects allow more flexibility and reduce the chances that your program will compete for resources.
- What will you gain in this case by sharing? Often, this just increases runtime and implementation complexity... but there *can* be gains. Without identifying those gains, you should stick to multiple instances to reduce complexity.
- Multiple instances allow your program to perform multiple asynchronous requests, based on what they need. Multiple async requests is fine (but it will obviously be slow if you have too many active requests).
- Most programs are more logical and easy to maintain when the objects they depend on allow multiple instances (they do not enforce sharing).

Assume multiple instances (1) until have identified a problem. Even after the problem is identified, you can usually avoid sharing.

To determine which consumes less memory requires much more information. If the objects you are considering sharing are not huge (very unlikely), they themselves are not problems wrt memory consumption.

Either approach proposed can result in more memory consumption - it depends entirely on the context and execution. We'll need some more information to answer this specifically.

This is not to imply that sharing is bad, but sharing usually complicates things because you need to design objects to behave predictably when shared (especially since you are operating in a multithreaded context).

Ask yourself:

- What significant benefit(s) would sharing `WebServices` provide?
- How would sharing `WebServices` improve your program and reduce complexity?

It's likely the case that the `WebServices` map stuff does not interact with the audio stuff. In that case, `WebServices` may be a good candidate for a base class, where the audio and map services are separate subclasses (assuming the `WebServices` class is already complex).

Comment: @anonymous_downvoter That's really not helpful unless you justify your action.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I'll go with option 1 in that case. To your last point, both the audio and map classes POST to the server. I had not considered putting the code in the base class because I wanted to reduce complexity in that base class as much as possible but I may be making it more complicated than it has to be. In any case, thanks for your response.

Comment: @thekevinscott Yes, it's really hard to say without seeing the program, but one *general* measure of complexity that I make is the number of ivars required to implement the class. If it exceeds three, there's a good chance the program can be simplified by division. Also, you're welcome =)

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a singleton for your WebServices class and use a shared instance. It seems this is the design pattern you require here.

With regard to the efficiency part of the question, the second option is more efficient purely because you're not storing as much data in RAM. The difference however, assuming your classes are not storing too much internally, is likely to be unnoticable.

```
@interface WebServices: NSObject
{
}

+ (WebServices*)sharedInstance;
@end

static WebServices *sharedInstance;
@implementation WebSerivces

+ (WebServices*)sharedInstance
{

  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if (!sharedInstance)
      sharedInstance = [[WebServices alloc] init];

    return sharedInstance;
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I haven't used singletons before in Objective-C, so I'll go off to the documentation and do some reading. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an `NSOperationQueue` with a number of `NSOperation`s, instead of a WebServices singleton.

Look at this [sweet example from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html) where they do this for concurrent image-downloading. It's a Mac example, but all the classes shown are available on iOS. They use `NSInvocationOperation`, but you can use an `NSOperation` subclass, or an `NSBlockOperation` for cleaner code.

You can add these from anywhere to a single queue, by calling `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue];` to fetch the main queue singleton. The singleton's job, in this case, is only to manage the queue (so not too many downloads happen at once), not to do any data processing (that's all handled by your `NSOperation`).

Comment: Thanks Kenny, I'll look into this. Do you think this would be useful for sporadic interaction with a server; i.e., the occasional POST from my two separate classes?

Comment: There's not a lot of overhead for NSOperationQueue. So, yes. Even if you're not doing tonnes of network stuff, this is a pretty good design pattern for async http.